# Javascript Code work on HTML and doesn't work in JSF

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, jsf-2

I have a working code in HTML page with out any probems , but when i write it in JSF page it doesnt work and i don't know why because the codes are similar and i don't see the difference . do you know what make jsf code doesnt work like HTML ??

Here you will have both of code HTML and JSF

HTML CODE :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>OrgChart | Performance 2000 nodes</title>

    <script src="./getorgchart.js"></script>
    <link href="./getorgchart.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #people {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="people"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var source = [];
    source.push({ id: 1, parentId: null, nodeId: "id: 1", title: "title: 1", other: "root" });
    var i = 1;
    while (i < 1000){
        addChildren(i)
        i = i + 1;
    }

    function addChildren(i){
        var lastId = source[source.length - 1].id;
        source.push({ id: lastId + 1, parentId: i, nodeId: "id: " + (lastId + 1), title: "title: " + (lastId + 1) });
        source.push({ id: lastId + 2, parentId: i, nodeId: "id: " + (lastId + 2), title: "title: " + (lastId + 2) });
    }


    var orgChart = new getOrgChart(document.getElementById("people"),{
        theme: "annabel",
        linkType: "B",
        primaryFields: ["nodeId", "title", "other"],
        photoFields: ["image"],
        gridView: true,
        enableSearch: false,
        dataSource: source
    });
    </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

JSF CODE :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

    <f:view contentType="text/html">  
        <h:head>
            <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
            <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
            <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />

            <f:facet name="first">  
                <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
                <title>Title</title> 
            </f:facet>

    <script src="http://www.getorgchart.com/GetOrgChart/getorgchart/getorgchart.js"></script>
    <link href="http://www.getorgchart.com/GetOrgChart/getorgchart/getorgchart.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        </h:head>


 <h:body style="margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;">  

                   <h:form >  

                    <div id="people" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;"></div>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                     <![CDATA[ 
                         var source = [];
                    source.push({ id: 1, parentId: null, nodeId: "id: 1", title: "title: 1", other: "root" });
                    var i = 1;
                    while (i < 1000){
                        addChildren(i)
                        i = i + 1;
                    }

                    function addChildren(i){
                        var lastId = source[source.length - 1].id;
                        source.push({ id: lastId + 1, parentId: i, nodeId: "id: " + (lastId + 1), title: "title: " + (lastId + 1) });
                        source.push({ id: lastId + 2, parentId: i, nodeId: "id: " + (lastId + 2), title: "title: " + (lastId + 2) });
                    }


                    var orgChart = new getOrgChart(document.getElementById("people"),{
                        theme: "annabel",
                        linkType: "B",
                        primaryFields: ["nodeId", "title", "other"],
                        photoFields: ["image"],
                        gridView: true,
                        enableSearch: false,
                        dataSource: source
                    });
                ]]>
    </script>

 </h:form>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

Comment: Please define "_doesn't work_".

Comment: You most likely have errors in the browser console!!!

Answer (score -1):

Thank you i followed  @Kukeltje advice by using browser console and this the working code after modification :

i changed `<![CDATA[` to `//<![CDATA[`

I changed `document.getElementById("Idform:people")` to `document.getElementById("people")`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

    <f:view contentType="text/html">  
        <h:head>
            <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
            <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
            <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />

            <f:facet name="first">  
                <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
                <title>Title</title> 
            </f:facet>

    <script src="./getorgchart.js"> </script>
    <link href="./getorgchart.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        </h:head>


 <h:body style="margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;">  

                   <h:form id="formId">  

                    <div id="people" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;" ></div>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                     //<![CDATA[

                         var source = [];
                    source.push({ id: 1, parentId: null, nodeId: "id: 1", title: "title: 1", other: "root" });
                    var i = 1;
                    while (i < 1000){
                        addChildren(i)
                        i = i + 1;
                    }

                    function addChildren(i){
                        var lastId = source[source.length - 1].id;
                        source.push({ id: lastId + 1, parentId: i, nodeId: "id: " + (lastId + 1), title: "title: " + (lastId + 1) });
                        source.push({ id: lastId + 2, parentId: i, nodeId: "id: " + (lastId + 2), title: "title: " + (lastId + 2) });
                    }


                    var orgChart = new getOrgChart(document.getElementById("people"),{
                        theme: "annabel",
                        linkType: "B",
                        primaryFields: ["nodeId", "title", "other"],
                        photoFields: ["image"],
                        gridView: true,
                        enableSearch: false,
                        dataSource: source
                    });

                //]]>
    </script>

 </h:form>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

Comment: IF you do post an answer even if it is a duiplicate, post **what** you changed and why. And I doubt your change is good. As far as I can see it should still fail

Comment: Downvote... This is not correct. You already had `document.getElementById("people")` in your original question! And I see that in the answer the form has an id and in the original question it did not. Please take care in creating good answers